# Does c++ linker throw away what is not needed or adds only what is needed?

Tags: c++, linker

If a linker starts satisfying missing symbols until it gets to the point where all needed symbols are satisfied we call "adding only what is needed". On the other hand starting with a full collection of symbols and then scanning based on some algorithm to remove the symbols that are not needed we call "throwing". For me semantically it is more correct we to describe this aspect of the linking process as adding only what is needed.

I am curious is the stackoverflow community agrees with that, because I believe it makes a stronger argument to rely on such linkers features.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "add"? The linker doesn't generate any code, so it can only work with what it gets from the compiler and assembler.

Comment: I am involved in a multi-platform projects that rely on multiple linkers - I am looking for a generalization - which is more correct.

Comment: Do you think there *is* a semantic difference? I don't... what is needed gets linked in, what's not needed is not used. Same thing either way.

Comment: I'll repeat the question, what do you mean by "add"? I can't say if your mental model is correct if I don't know what it is, and I don't understand what are saying is added by the linker.

Comment: I think adding only what is needed is a stronger argument (seems safe to rely on)  than expecting they to do a good job of clearing what is not needed.

Comment: What's the difference? There are things that are needed, and things that are not needed. Are you imagining some third set, that would be handled by "adding what is needed" but not handled by "throw away what is not needed"?

Comment: If a linker starts from the main function, detect the missing symbols, goes through the available symbols and adds the missing so far - this is "adding". If it starts from everything then it scans the needs and removes the symbols that are not used from any other - this will be "throwing"

Comment: @DevSolar - if there is an argument about it, obviously not everybody involved believes it is black and white as you describing it.

Comment: @gsf You should probably incorporate your comment "If a linker starts..." into the question in some form - it will clarify what you're actually asking about.

Answer (score 3):

All linkers work in an additive mode. It's best explained using graph theory.

A linker starts by identifying one or more entry points (`main` for an executable, exported functions for a library). These entry points must be included.

However, these export points may be contained in larger segments/chunks (many compilers cannot or do not package individual functions and data). Anything contained in the same chunk/segment will automatically be included.

Furthermore, as functions call other functions, a linker may need to add those functions as well - and again, compiler limitations can cause a lot of extra stuff to be dragged in when the chunks are too big. This step is called "resolving dependencies" and usually is done recursively until no more functions are missing.

Why are these chunks so big? A common problem is that compiler/linker pairs cannot communicate dependencies. If the linker cannot be told that X depends on Y, the compiler must put X and Y in the same segment. This tends to escalate to the point where an entire .cpp file ends up in the same segment, unfortunately - and all those unneeded function drag in their unneeded dependencies. I've seen executables balloon to 600 MB because of this.

Answer (score 2):

Linkers are *resolving references*. They "look" at the symbol tables of the to-be-linked object files, and resolve those references -- or spit "unresolved reference" errors if none of the given object files satisfies said reference.

So you would be justified to say they are "adding". (It took your comment / edit to see where you were coming from.)

*However*, there are limitations, depending on the capabilities of the linker used. You might be (and probably are...) looking at a linker that can only decide to either link a whole object file, or not. In that case, it is a factor *of your code structure* whether the linker *can* do a good job omitting unneeded object code. If all you have is one big object file, well, it will get linked in as soon as a single symbol from that object file is required.

So it might be "adding" more than you'd like to -- or "fail to remove". It's really just quibbling.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question has many "it depends".

For example, it depends on the capabilities of your compiler and linker.  Some linkers may not have the intelligence to detect unused functions.

Some compilers may only drop functions if the optimization levels are set at specific levels.

The function may have to be part of the code you are building or in a static library in order for the compiler to drop it.

Some compilers may throw in all the functions in a library whether they are needed or not; depending on the optimization level.

*It depends*.

Give a more specialized example.

Comment: I understand the "it depends" part - but getting in specifics will defeat the conceptual general goal of the question.

Comment: You are not going to get a specific answer to a general question.  Perhaps the most specific answer to your question is "yes."

Comment: For many discussions I have I come to this website and I check what most of the people think, based on the voring scores. When I am aligned with the most voted answer(s) this gives me confidence that it is not just me who has this opinion and recently I even use links to the questions as part of the argumentation I provide.

I am not looking for a simple specific answer, but an analysis on the topic that the stackoverflow community to decide with voting for one or another.

Answer (score 1):

Classically, a linker will start by adding *all* of the object files you've specified. Then it will go through *static link libraries*, looking for modules that define symbols that are required by those object files or by earlier libraries - any module that defines a symbol is linked in total. Modules that don't define a required symbol are not linked.

Today's linkers are more complex and are capable of performing an optimization step, but the details should come from the documentation of the *specific* build system you're using.